# Kundera compatibility with Cassandra 3.0.1

Tags: cassandra, kundera

Is kundera-cassandra 3.3 fully compatible with Cassandra 3.0.1? As I see, kundera-cassandra uses the `cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar` and referring to this http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/common/driverMatrix.html?scroll=driverMatrix__driver-cmpt-matrix it seams that this driver is not compatible with Version 3 of Cassandra.

So is there a way to use kundera-cassandra fully compatible with Cassandra 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kundera is currently not fully compatible with Cassandra 3.0/+. This will be available in its 3.4 release. To find the datastore versions supported :

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Datastores-Supported